# A particular bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory

Is there any particular name of a bipartite graph in which all the nodes belong to the roots have equal degrees and all the nodes belong to the Leafs have the equal degree?

Comment: Perhaps a [biregular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biregular_graph) graph? Of course, graph theory terminology is notoriously non-standard.

Comment: @JoshuaMundinger that seems like fairly logical terminology, but as with anything not-completely-standard, define terms explicitly.

Comment: @BobKrueger The definition is in the linked page: each color class has constant degree.